# Running Jasper report in Jdeveloper ORA-00904 is thrown

Tags: sql, jdeveloper

I have an issue that is quite simply driving me nuts...

I am running JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0, I am also running Jasper Reports 4.5. I have a class that contains several methods. Each of which runs a seprate Jasper report made with iReport.

I am also testing this in the Intergrated WLS.

When a user click a button it runs said report, works great if only calling one report. As soon as I try and call 2 or more reports the first report will work but all other throw this error:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException ORA-00904: "ID" : invalid identifer

---

Example

```
public String button () thorws ClassNotFoundException, Exception
{
   Reports runReport = new Reports ();
   runReport.FirstReport;
   runReport.SecondReport;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Not sure where to trace this error to, as each method in class Reports runs fine when only ran by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Your code sample do not show what you do. It's not even correct java syntax.
The stack trace you get should have more information (e.g. the while query) which you should sahre.

Comment: I am simply showing the method, to illustrate the structure when the button is clicked. I am unable to show the complete stack trace this is why I posted the error it thorws. As for the query, it works fine when I run separatly.

Comment: "I am unable to show the complete stack trace this is why I posted the error it thorws"

Comment: "I am unable to show the complete stack trace this is why I posted the error it thorws" Stack traces repeat themselves after a while. so just copying the relevant piece of the trace would have been enough. The information you provide isn't really exhausive

Comment: Hello Frank, turns out this error is trhown when Jasper Reports 4.0 is used when the jrmxl file is made in iReport 4.6. There is a way to change this under Tools-->Options -->Compability.  Sorry I am unable to produce the stack trace the computer it resides on is not connected to the net, and the dvd burn has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Google for the error message and you find hints like this:

[Intermittent ORA-00904: : invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885108/intermittent-ora-00904-invalid-identifier)

that point to possible RDBMS issues. Looking up thebugs mentioned in the thread it seems databases versions earlier than 10.2 are impacted if you reconnect to different schemas with similar objects. Not sure this is your case due to a lack of information in your question.

Frank